# Gson TypeAdapters cross-reference problem

Tags: java, gson

I have a `TypeAdapter<A>` for a class A, and another one for a class B. The A class contains a field of type B. Now, here is the problem: when I write the serialization of my `TypeAdapter<A>`, I would like to get the serialization result of my B class as String to put it as a value for the field of my A class.

Example:

```java
public class A {
    private final B b;
    // ...
}

public class B {
    // ...
}

public class ATypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<A> {
    public void write(JsonWriter out, EconomyContainer container) throws IOException {
        out.beginObject();

        out.name("b_json_value").value(/* Here, I want to set the JSON serialization of my B class as String*/);

        out.endObject();
    }

    @Override
    public EconomyContainer read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        out.beginObject();

        while (in.hasNext()) {
            if (in.nextName().equals("b_json_value")) {
                // Here, I want to use the read the String and deserialize it with the JSON value
            }
        }

        out.name("b_json_value").value(/* Here, I want to set the JSON serialization of my B class as String*/);

        out.endObject();
    }
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

I tried passing an instance of Gson into my class constructor to use the required TypeAdapter, but this couldn't work as when I create a new GsonBuilder, that's when I have to fill in my TypeAdapters, so I can't pass a Gson instance onto the classes that would need it as the variable containing it is not yet initialised.

Comment: You're on the right track. Use `TypeAdaptorFactory` to pass the `Gson` instance to your `TypeAdaptor`.

Comment: Here, I found an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58043010/15224052. Probably a duplicate.

Comment: Adding to what @Oliver wrote, your `TypeAdapterFactory` would look up the adapter for `B`, then create and return an adapter for `A` which delegates handling for `"b_json_value"` to the methods `TypeAdapter.toJson` and `TypeAdapter.fromJson` of `B`'s adapter. (assuming that I understood you correctly and you actually want a nested JSON document string)